# Variable value check isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a `<div>` I'm clicking on to change the value of a variable. The variable changes but the `if(oneorzero == 0)` never works. It always continues to `== 0`. Even though the variable is different, it still acts the same. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I left a part out. After I change the variable, I need to check the onmousedown function to see if it worked. This is my issue.

```
var oneorzero = 0;

var onmousedownfunction= function() {
if(oneorzero == 0){
   alert('One or Zero equals 0');
   //Do something
};
if(oneorzero == 1){
   alert('One or Zero equals 1');
   //Do something
};
};

$('.class').click(function(){
    val_class = $(this).attr('value');
    if(val_class == '0'){
        $(this).attr('value','1');
        oneorzero = 1;
    };
    if(val_class == '1'){
        $(this).attr('value','0');
        oneorzero = 0;
    };
});

$(canvas).mousedown(onmousedownfunction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place that inside the click event.

The way you have written will only execute once when the page loads.

Also use `console.log` instead of `alert` as it is a lot more elegant;

Also you can use `parseInt` and eliminate an extra variable using it

```
$('.class').click(function () {
    var val_class = parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10),
        oneorzero;

    if (val_class === 0) {
        oneorzero = 1;

    } else if (val_class == 1) {
        oneorzero = 0;
    }
    $(this).attr('value', oneorzero );
    console.log(val_class);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GBSX2/1/)**

The same can be written in a single line and can eliminate the `if else` completely by using a ternary operators

```
$('.class').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        val_class = parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10) === 0 ? 1 : 0 ;
    $(this).attr('value', val_class).text(val_class);

    console.log(val_class);
}).click();
```

**[Another Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GBSX2/2/)**

[Mousedown fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GBSX2/3/)

Comment: I left a part of the question out. After the variable has been changed, i want to check the onmousedown function.

Comment: What is canvas here.. Is it a variable

Comment: Body or Canvas. Regardless, on the mousedown, no matter how many times I change the oneorzero variable, it still see it as 0.

Comment: Should I be calling the onmousedownfunction after the Class click? Is that what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not calling the function directly. The onmousedown event will trigger the function. So it does not matter where ever it is placed. Just trigger the `click` event after declaring it so that it will have a value beforehand

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Split the conditions inside the listener with an `else`, or the flow will always fall through to the second condition:

```js
if (val_class == '0') {
    $(this).attr('value', '1');
    oneorzero = 1;
} else if (val_class == '1') { // no 'else', and we'd be setting 'value' again
    $(this).attr('value', '0');
    oneorzero = 0;
}
```